# if statement always giving same answer python beginner

Tags: python, if-statement

python always answers you are likely to be eligible for work even though I typed a number under 18

```
question1= raw_input("are you fat?")
if question1== ("yes"):
    print ("sorry you are not fit for work")
elif question1== ("no"):
    print ("you may be eligible for work, move on to the next question please")
    question2= raw_input("how old are you?")
    if question2 >= 18:
        print ("you are likely to be eligible for work")
    elif question2 < 18:
        print ("sorry come back when you're older")
```

Comment: You need `question2 = int(raw_input(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a string (`question2`) and an integer (`18`). Contrary to other languages like PHP, the string is not automatically converted to an int beforehand, and the int is not converted to a string either.

In such a comparison, an int is *always* < a string. You must compare `int(question2)` with 18.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) for the full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because raw input is asking for a undefined string of characters not an integer 
when python takes in the output it receives

```
question2 = "16"
```

Rather than

```
question2 = 16
```

Here would be a fix to your code:

```
question1= raw_input("are you fat?")
if question1== ("yes"):
    print ("sorry you are not fit for work")
elif question1== ("no"):
    print ("you may be eligible for work, move on to the next question please")
    question2= int(raw_input("how old are you?"))
        if question2 >= 18:
            print ("you are likely to be eligible for work")
        elif question2 < 18:
            print ("sorry come back when you're older")
```

Because now python converts the string into an integer

```
question2= int(raw_input("how old are you?"))
```

I would recommend using python 3 though (This is my opinion) It makes this simpler

-Joshua